# Heat Cable: directly powered with 230V AC vs. 12V DC with step-down efficiency

Tags: buck, heat, efficiency, step-down, loss

Is it any less efficient to drive a 12V version of a heat cable from a step-down buck than directly powering a 230V version of it directly from the wall?

Comment: The step-down will not have 100% efficiency. But if you just wanted to heat up the room anyway...

Comment: So it makes sense to use a 12V version since it's easier to dim via PWM?

Comment: Can you arrange it so that the heat dissipated by the voltage converter goes to where the heating takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course 12V is less efficient because of convrter loss. But you have to consider the safety of two different systems. If you want to heat your bed, I would reccomend you to use a 12V vesion, but no buck, rather and isolated PSU.
If you will heating a concrete floor, then a 230VAC is more appropiate, however a GFCI device might be needed.

Comment: If you want to heat a bed, then it might be better to get a manufactured one. Then you can sue them if you wake up dead.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Most of bed heaters are 230VAC, in the manual is saying: don't use while in bed. So even with manufactured one you can take a sleep.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I meant can take a long sleep, without waking.

Comment: Ha ha, it lost something in the translation both ways :)